# Export graphic with localised text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, export

I have graphic picture that requires simple text. However, the text needs to be localised. I have different layers for this text (one for English, one for German, ...). I need to export this picture (I use **Save for Web & Devices** tool). However, since the text is localised, I have to export a lot of pictures (one for English, one for German, ...). My question is: Is there any tool in Photoshop, that allows to export all localised images at once? Now I have to hide all text layers but one and export them sequentially.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Yes it's possible. You could use [data sets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html#:~:text=Create%20data-driven%20graphics%201%20Rename%20a%20variable.%20Choose,5%20Creating%20data%20sets%20in%20external%20files.%20) - it's a bit like using mail merge in word processors, but using graphics and text.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30768/combinations-and-permutations-of-photoshop-layers

Comment: I see. It looks good. However, I have this image split into slices. Is it possible to use datasets with slices? When I export datasets to separate PSDs and then I use Image Processor to batch convert to .jpg, the resulting images are not split into slices.

Comment: @Tom11 - I'm not sure. That may be a bit more complex than what the feature was actually designed for. Maybe instead do it on one image at a time. So, separate PSDs for each slice might work. Anything more complicated may require sripting.

Comment: @Billy Kerr Do you think that it's possible to do that by scripting?

Comment: @Tom11 -  I'm no programming expert. Sorry.  I was just looking at the link Scott suggested. Not sure if it could be modified for your needs.

Comment: OK, I will post new question for that. Thank you very much for your help.